# fatal error: 'grpcpp/grpcpp.h' file not found C++

Tags: c++, g++, protocol-buffers, grpc, protoc

**Context**

I have been working with C++ for about the past 5-6 months and I'm beginning to learn gRPC. I have followed many tutorials online to get started, but I want to build a client-server communication app from scratch. Probably a bit too much, but I'm doing my best to understand how to get it all to work from the ground up rather than downloading, typing 'make', and then having a working product that I don't know how to implement into my own projects.

***Goal: Create and run a simple C++ gRPC client-server communication***

**Versions**

Using VSCode IDE.

- Protoc = libprotoc 3.17.3
- gRPC = 1.41.1
- make = 3.81

**Files**

*mathtest.proto*

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_package = "ex.grpc";

package mathtest;

// Defines the service
service MathTest {
    // Function invoked to send the request
    rpc sendRequest (MathRequest) returns (MathReply) {}
}

// The request message containing requested numbers
message MathRequest {
    int32 a = 1;
    int32 b = 2;
}

// The response message containing response
message MathReply {
    int32 result = 1;
}
```

*server.cpp*

```
#include <string>

#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>
#include "mathtest.grpc.pb.h"

using grpc::Server;
using grpc::ServerBuilder;
using grpc::ServerContext;
using grpc::Status;

using mathtest::MathTest;
using mathtest::MathRequest;
using mathtest::MathReply;

class MathServiceImplementation final : public MathTest::Service {
    Status sendRequest(
        ServerContext* context, 
        const MathRequest* request, 
        MathReply* reply
    ) override {
        int a = request->a();
        int b = request->b();

        reply->set_result(a * b);

        return Status::OK;
    } 
};

void Run() {
    std::string address("0.0.0.0:5000");
    MathServiceImplementation service;

    ServerBuilder builder;

    builder.AddListeningPort(address, grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
    builder.RegisterService(&service);

    std::unique_ptr<Server> server(builder.BuildAndStart());
    std::cout << "Server listening on port: " << address << std::endl;

    server->Wait();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Run();

    return 0;
}
```

*client.cpp*

```
#include <string>

#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>
#include "mathtest.grpc.pb.h"

using grpc::Channel;
using grpc::ClientContext;
using grpc::Status;

using mathtest::MathTest;
using mathtest::MathRequest;
using mathtest::MathReply;

class MathTestClient {
    public:
        MathTestClient(std::shared_ptr<Channel> channel) : stub_(MathTest::NewStub(channel)) {}

    int sendRequest(int a, int b) {
        MathRequest request;

        request.set_a(a);
        request.set_b(b);

        MathReply reply;

        ClientContext context;

        Status status = stub_->sendRequest(&context, request, &reply);

        if(status.ok()){
            return reply.result();
        } else {
            std::cout << status.error_code() << ": " << status.error_message() << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
    }

    private:
        std::unique_ptr<MathTest::Stub> stub_;
};

void Run() {
    std::string address("0.0.0.0:5000");
    MathTestClient client(
        grpc::CreateChannel(
            address, 
            grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials()
        )
    );

    int response;

    int a = 5;
    int b = 10;

    response = client.sendRequest(a, b);
    std::cout << "Answer received: " << a << " * " << b << " = " << response << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    Run();

    return 0;
}
```

**Steps taken for compilation**

1. Use `mathtest.proto` to create the necessary files via 'protoc' (or protobuf) by executing these: `protoc --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=/opt/homebrew/bin/grpc_cpp_plugin mathtest.proto` & `protoc --cpp_out=. mathtest.proto`

This creates the following files:

- `mathtest.pb.h`
- `mathtest.pb.cc`
- `mathtest.grpc.pb.h`
- `mathtest.grpc.pb.cc`

2. Compile client.cpp & server.cpp files to create executable binaries using these commands: `g++ -std=c++17 client.cpp mathtest.pb.cc mathtest.grpc.pb.cc -o client 'pkg-config --libs protobuf grpc++'` (NOTE: in this post, I use a single quote in the command line, but in the actual command I use a backtick; just wanted to make that clear)

**Errors**

As you may notice, I can't get to compiling the server because I can't get past the client compilation first. After executing the above command in step 2 of compilation, this is my output:

```
g++ -std=c++17 client.cpp mathtest.pb.cc mathtest.grpc.pb.cc -o client `pkg-config --libs protobuf grpc++`
client.cpp:4:10: fatal error: 'grpcpp/grpcpp.h' file not found
#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
In file included from mathtest.pb.cc:4:
./mathtest.pb.h:10:10: fatal error: 'google/protobuf/port_def.inc' file not found
#include <google/protobuf/port_def.inc>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
In file included from mathtest.grpc.pb.cc:5:
./mathtest.pb.h:10:10: fatal error: 'google/protobuf/port_def.inc' file not found
#include <google/protobuf/port_def.inc>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [client] Error 1
```

**Here's my real confusion...**

C++ intellisense has no issues finding these files. My $PATH variables point to these folders, and my VS Code include path also point to these folders. I'm unsure where I am going wrong here...

echo $PATH returns this:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/opt/homebrew/include:/opt/homebrew/Cellar:/opt/homebrew/opt/libtool/libexec/gnubin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/tzeller/.local/bin
```

The folders in question ('google' & 'grcpp') live within `/opt/homebrew/include` and they hold the necessary files as well...

What am I missing??

Comment: $PATH has nothing to do with preprocessor include paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your compile command to

```
g++ -std=c++17 client.cpp mathtest.pb.cc mathtest.grpc.pb.cc -o client `pkg-config --libs --cflags protobuf grpc++`
```

The `--cflags` bit asks pkg-config to spit out the necessary parameters for setting the header search path (on my system `-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/grpc/1.41.1/include` and others)

Comment: Thank you; this worked. Now onto the next problem that has arisen... linker errors.